# SSRS Multiple Rows in One Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a Report in SSRS 2008. The report is in a table. I have a row where I need to list multiple names. Right now it creates a row for each name, but I want to combined them so they are all in one row. I am querying CRM 2011 so I am using FetchXML. Is there anyway to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use matrix view and make Name column as Row Column.